# O evento keypress do Javascrit não funciona em mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, javascript-eventos, event-listener

O código JavaScript abaixo, que serve para "barrar" caracter > (asc 60) só funciona em dispositivos desktop e não em dispositivos mobiles.

```
<textarea name='notes' id='ta' wrap='physical' cols='65' rows='8' style='width: 80%;' tabindex='14'></textarea>

<script>
var ta = document.getElementById("ta");
ta.addEventListener('keypress',
    function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode == 60) {
           alert('N\u00e3o use <');
           e.preventDefault();
       }
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Parece que o [KeyboardEvent.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) esta Deprecated

Answer (score -1):

[beforeinput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/beforeinput_event)  
[InputEvent.data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent/data)

```js
var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
ta.addEventListener('beforeinput', evt => {
    if (evt.inputType === 'insertText' && evt.data.charCodeAt(0) === 60) {
        alert('N\u00e3o use <');
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

```html
<textarea name='notes' id='ta' wrap='hard' cols='65' rows='8' style='width: 80%;' tabindex='14' onpaste='return(false)'></textarea>
```

```js
var ta = document.getElementById('ta');
ta.addEventListener(window.TextEvent && 'name' in window.TextEvent ? 'textInput' : 'keypress',
    function (evt) {
        if ((evt.which || evt.data.charCodeAt(0)) === 60) {
            alert('N\u00e3o use <');
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
    }, false);
```

```html
<textarea name='notes' id='ta' wrap='hard' cols='65' rows='8' style='width: 80%;' tabindex='14' onpaste='return(false)'></textarea>
```

https://www.outsystems.com/blog/posts/create-input-mask-for-mobile/

Answer (score -2):

```js
var ta = document.getElementById("ta");
ta.onkeydown = (e) => {
       const keyCode = e.which || e.keyCode;
       if (keyCode === 188 ) {
           alert('N\u00e3o use <');
           e.preventDefault();
       }
    }
```

```html
<textarea name='notes' id='ta' wrap='physical' cols='65' rows='8' style='width: 80%;' tabindex='14'></textarea>
```

O problema está com evento `Keypress`

Isto porque, certamente há algum problema com o evento `keypress` no navegador Android (ou seja, Chrome para mobile). Tente substituí-lo pelo evento `keydown`, isso geralmente funciona bem.

Comment: Não funcionou, nem com desktop nem com mobile

Comment: Podes por favor tentar agora

Comment: @Roseli funcionou? O resto é uma questão de colocar o codigo certo para cada caracter... https://keycode.info/

Comment: Olha, agradeço, mas funcionou só no desktop....